# Google python library 404 errors with Google Analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics

Has anyone had problems getting the Python client library for Google Analytics to work? I can instantiate the objects and authenticate just fine but once I attempt to retrieve data the client libraries throw 404 errors. Even running the demo code included in the client library files. The following is the error generated when running account_feed_demo.py

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\analytics\client.py", line 61, in get_account_feed
**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\client.py", line 640, in get_feed
**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\client.py", line 319, in request
RequestError)
RequestError: Server responded with: 404, <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
    <style>
```

I am using version 2.0.18 of the client library and Python 2.7